# Configuring Validation Context to use a DI Container

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am doing ASP.NET Web API 2 (i.e. `ApiController`)

We are deriving from `ValidationAttribute` to create custom validators. Our validator needs a dependency. During ASP model binding, validators are called automatically for all properties where `ValidationAttribute` is set.

I noticed `validationcontext` has a `GetService` method. But it does not work. May be it needs to be configured to look somewhere.

A) My question is, how can I tell ASP that when invoking validator's `IsValid` method, use a specific implementation of `IServiceProvider` inside `validationcontext` ?

b) Is there a way to turn off "Auto validation" for `ValidationAttributes` in ASP that occurs during model binding ? That way I can control validation explicitly using `TryValidateObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a service filter?

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(FilterClass))]
```

Not sure if its the same for asp.net mvc 4, but this is how it is done is asp.net core: https://andrewlock.net/injecting-services-into-validationattributes-in-asp-net-core/